# Issue connecting to office wifi but able to connect other wifis

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have issue connecting to my office WIFI but im able to connect to other WIFI outside my office.
All the people in the office are able to connect to office wifi with no issue.
Please suggest me on this.

Additional Info:

- Security Type-No authentication (Open) & Encryption type- WEP
- WiFi has plenty of signal

What I have tried so far:

- Reinstalled driver from Dell website
- Cleared all wireless networks from the stored networks list
- Restarted multiple times

Comment: What happens when you try and connect.

Comment: When im trying to connect it just goes on Identifying the networks & comes up with limited or no connectivity message.

Comment: More details are needed to be able to help you. What device are you trying to connect? What type of security? Any error messages and what do they say? Are the wireless card drives up to date for the device you are trying to connect? All Windows updates installed? Etc...

Comment: @Venky | What steps have you tried to resolve the issue?

Comment: •Reinstalled driver from Dell website
•Cleared all wireless networks from the stored networks list
•Restarted multiple times

Comment: @Venky | Is your system set to get an IP automatically? Have you turned off firewalls and antivirus to test if this is the problem. Have you run troubleshooter on the connection?

Comment: Yes Matthew its set to automatically obtain the IP & both antivirus & firewalls are turned off.

Comment: When I run the troubleshooter I come up with the following message "Problem with wireless adapter or access point".

Comment: Have you checked the event logs. Given the that the Troubleshooter failed, there should be additional details in Event Viewer about it.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Make sure Your Wireless Network Configuration has not Changed:**
If the access point settings are changed to require using a specific Wi-Fi channel number, some computers may be unable to discover it so Confirm the Wi-Fi channel number and encryption keys on your router have not recently changed

2) **Make sure there's no IP Address Conflicts on your network:**
If your computer and another on the network both have the same IP address, the conflict between them will prevent either from working properly online.

3) **Check the computer for malware:**
A computer's network adapter hardware might suddenly fail due to overheating or age. Failures in the operating system software that control the adapter, on the other hand, can occur frequently especially with computers that are heavily used. Viruses and worms also may disable or block a computer's network interfaces from functioning properly. Finally, if using a laptop, transporting it from one location to another can corrupt the state of its network.

4) Try `netsh winsock reset` command to reset TCP/IP stack.